# which hypothesis for boundedness of this function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $v:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ be a positive function such that $$\exists T,q>0\,\,s.t.\,\, \forall t\in[0,\infty),\,\,\int_t^{t+T} v(\tau) d\tau \le q$$
I'm looking for the "less restrictive" possible condition which together with the equation above ensures that $v(\tau)$ is bounded in $[0,\infty)$. Any guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding boundedness on $[0,T)$, the condition on $v$ translates to $v\in L^1([0,T))$ (let $t=0$). What you are asking is what extra condition you can put on an integrable function for it to be bounded.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm looking for some "lightweight" condition to be sure that $v$ is bounded. Sorry, I corrected the question since I'm actually interested in boundedness on the whole $[0,\infty)$ no more just in $[0,T)$. My doubt is: ok that integral is finite, but actually I don't know whether $v$ assumes or not unbounded values for some null-measure subsets of $[t,t+T]$, therefore I'm looking for some extra condition. Do you think Locally Lipschitz condition to work?

Comment: Locally Lipschitz implies continuous. If $v$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ then it is bounded on any bounded interval.

Comment: yes sure... What other hypothesis may I use?

Comment: Other than asking directly for $v$ to be bounded, you could impose that $v$ has weak derivatives in $L^p$, $p>1$,  of any bounded interval.

Comment: Ok, thank you a lot Sir.